# Review help regarding loops

Tags: c, loops

As it is time to study for finals, I have to cover some detailed information regarding loops.I am currently stuck on this question

```
int main(void) {
  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;
  while (y < 10) {
     x = 0;
     while (x != y) {// 
       x = x + 3; // how many times will we do this statement?
     }
     printf(“x is %d\n”, x);
     y = y + 1;
  }
}
```

Basically, I am looking to see **what the output is and how many times that statement we mentioned is run**. In other words what does printf output look like.

I hope you can help me with this.

Thank you so much.

Comment: It is mentioned on the code itself...how many times will that statement run

Comment: use a debugger and you will soon find out

Comment: I'll give you a clue -- it's a trick question. See if you can figure out why.

Comment: thank you but no thank you...i am trying to figure out the logic here and not exactly what to do using a debugger. I am looking to learn you logic that you used rather than finding the exact answer.

Comment: @Dunes: Go for it...that is what i am looking for!

Comment: A good idea is to get a pen and paper, write down the initial values of x and y and then go through each step, modifying x and y as necessary and writing down when a printf happens. When you get to a while statement look at your values of x and y to see what should happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line causes a problem

```
 x = 0;
 while (x != y) {// 
   x = x + 3; // how many times will we do this statement?
 }
```

when `y=1` since `x` will continue to increase until it reaches the maximum integer value (it cant equal y unless some overflow wrapping occurs - this will result in an infinite loop).

Answer (score 1):

First, due to the nature of the question and no official (that I know of) standard on overflow wrapping that isn't implementation-dependent, **the answer is formally **indeterminable****.

That said, *informally* lets crunch some numbers just for the hell of it. I'll compute this for 32bit `int`, though the numbers for 64bit are way-more impressive. The choice of `3` as the increment is highly advantageous, (perhaps by design?) as neither 2^32 nor 2^64 are evenly divisible by it, thereby making it perfect for overflow continuity.

Some key numbers that will make things easier:

```
 2147483646 := (715827882 * 3)
-2147483647 := (2147483646 + 3) with overflow
```

Y=0, X=0 immediately, so no iteration statements are executed.

1. Y=1, X=0,3,6,9...2147483646 after 715827882 increments. The next increment will overflow and X=-2147483647. Another 715827882 increments later,  X=-1. One more increment to get back in positive territory and X=2. Repeat the entire thing over again and X=1, A total of 4*715827882 + 3, sum=**2863311531**.
2. Y=2, X=0,3,6,9.... Recall from (1) above, it took 2*(715827882+1) increments to get around to 2, aka, one full pass. Therefore another 1431655766 executions, sum=**4294967297**
3. Y=3, For obvious reasons, Y=X=3 in one iteration. sum=**4294967298**
4. Y=4, Repeat (1), but add one more increment; Therefore 4*715827882 + 3 + 1 more iterations, or 2863311533. sum=**7158278830**
5. Y=5, Repeat (2), but add one more increment; Therefore 2*(715827882 + 1) + 1 more iterations, or 1431655767, sum=**8589934597**
6. Y=6, Repeat (3), but add one more increment; Therefore 1 + 1 more iterations,  sum=**8589934599**
7. Y=7, Repeat (4), but add one more increment; Therefore  4*715827882 + 3 + 1 + 1 more iterations, or 2863311533. sum=**11453246132**
8. Y=8, Repeat (5), but add one more increment; Therefore 2*(715827882 + 1 + 1) + 1 more iterations, or 1431655768, sum=**12884901900**
9. Y=9, Repeat (6), but add one more increment; Therefore 1 + 1 + 1 more iterations,  sum=**12884901903**

Assuming you can spin three hundred million iterations per second, it would take approximately **42.95 seconds** to finish.

I'll leave the 64bit calculation to be food for thought. However, just to ponder the actual numbers, a (val+=3) increment through the 64bit integer space will require **6148914691236517206** iterations, and some steps above require we do it twice, others once, and others not at all.

Modified test program to ensure we use 32bit signed int values:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void)
{
    int32_t x = 0;
    int32_t y = 0;
    uint64_t sum = 0;

    while (y < 10)
    {
        x = 0;
        while (x != y)
        {
            x = x + 3; ++sum;
        }
        printf("x is %d; sum=%" PRId64 "\n", x, sum);
        y = y + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
x is 0; sum=0
x is 1; sum=2863311531
x is 2; sum=4294967297
x is 3; sum=4294967298
x is 4; sum=7158278830
x is 5; sum=8589934597
x is 6; sum=8589934599
x is 7; sum=11453246132
x is 8; sum=12884901900
x is 9; sum=12884901903
```

Answer (score 0):

It's either a trick question, or a poorly thought out one (or perhaps is a more advanced question than it appears at first).

**The answer is indeterminable since it depends on the properties of integer overflow.**

I'll let you figure out why this is the case. If you don't see it at first, try working through a couple of iterations with pen and paper. If that raises further questions, feel free to ask. :)

Answer (score 0):

`while (x != y) {` may make the while loop infinite which will never break.

E.g.

- First loop x = 0, y = 0
- 2nd while does not execute.
- 2nd iteration x = 0, y = 1
- In 2nd while loop

  - iteration 1, x = 3
  - iteration 2, x = 6
  - And it continues as x will never be 1.

Answer (score 0):

i think your inner while, loops infinitly because of :

x = 0 and y = 1 then x = x + 3(x = 3) is always != 1 so it causes infinite loop